# POST method doesn't work (Fetch or Axios) in a react-native app (Android)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, fetch, content-type

I'm doing an `API CALL` width `POST` method either with `Axios` or `Fetch` but send the wrong `Content-Type` on Android.

Send `application/json; charset=utf-8` instead of `application/json`

It's working fine on iOS and `GET` method seems to work well on both platform.

1) My App was created with Create-React-Native App and working with Expo

2) What I've tried so far :

- I read a lot of topics (github / stackoverflow) with some changes to do : in the headers, send another content-type, changes received data in `Postman`, etc- Using `Axios` or `Fetch`

Example: `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`

Code I tried (basically the same)

```
fetch('URL', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'TOKEN': 'TOKEN',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
}).then((response) => console.log(response))
```

or

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: LOGIN_API_URL,
  headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'TOKEN': 'MyTestToken',
  },
  data: data,
}).then((response) => {console.log(response.data)})
```

The error I get :

`{title: "ERROR", code: "invalid ContentType", description: "Content-Type expeced: application/json,  Content-Type received: application/json; charset=utf-8", success: false}`

I would like to send the right `content-type: 'application/json'` for both platform : ios and android

If I missed some topics with the answer, sorry :)

Comment: do you have the react native debugger enabled? maybe this causes the error

Comment: No, I have everything disabled. The only infos I have are in my terminal because I run the app with 'expo start'.
I updated my topic with the exact error I get

Answer (score 2):

this looks like a bug on axios side (see https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/859 )
There seem to be a possible solution linked to whether the `data` parameter is provided or not (https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/86):

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/86#issuecomment-405930811

```
const config = {
  headers: {
    accept: 'application/json',
  },
  data: {},
};
```

I hope this can point you in the right direction.